# Embedded Jetty and graceful shutdown

Tags: java, jetty

I've dug through the Jetty documentation trying to find out how to properly configure an embedded Jetty to shut down gracefully, but I found it lacking.

The examples in [the documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) inconsequently use `setStopAtShutdown(true)`. However, there is no JavaDoc or explanation why this should be done. As far as I can tell, the default value is set to false.

Additionally, the `setGracefulShutdown()` method [changed to `setStopTimeout()` it seems](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03483.html), but this is not documented either.

So these are my questions:

1. Why would you set or not set stop at shutdown?
2. When would you override the stop timeout (defaults to 30 seconds)?
3. What other things should be taken into consideration when configuring Jetty for graceful shutdown?

Edit:
After some trial and error; discovered that setStopAtShutdown(true) is required if you want to have Jetty signal a shutdown event to any listeners such as Spring's ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: Hardest problem is to stop correctly deployed application, not jetty itself. Especially when it something complex with queries, thread pools and so on. I personally prefer to use embedded jetty with watchdog and stop it by killing process. Maybe this is not correct by idea of usage, but always working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The graceful shutdown procedure requests each worker thread to shut down (i.e. finish processing the current request, then don't accept any new requests and exit).  It then waits for a bit (configurable via the timeout), and if any threads remain, it kills them forcefully.  This can happen because the thread is taking a long time to process a request, for example, or because of a deadlock.  If you keep the default value of 30 seconds, it might take a little more than 30 seconds for the application to exit.  Reducing the value of the timeout will give you a faster shutdown time, but at the expense of potentially killing threads that were busy processing legitimate, active requests.

Answer (score 2):

The default `stopAtShutdown` seems to be true, see at http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty.xml?h=jetty-9.1.x, the timeout is also there, 5 seconds:

```
<Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
<Set name="stopTimeout">5000</Set>
```

Additionally, you may configure a LifeCycle.Listener for more specific cases, e.g., I use one to remove a pid file (among other things) when shutting down the server, I attach the listener in the Connector using addLifeCycleListener on the ServerConnector, in jetty xml, it looks like:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  ...
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        ...
        <Call name="addLifeCycleListener">
          <Arg>
            <New class="com.acme.jetty.ConnectorListener"/>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
```

and ConnectorListener.java would begin with something like:

```
package com.acme.jetty;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger;

public class ConnectorListener implements LifeCycle.Listener {
    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLogger(ConnectorListener.class);
    ...
    public void lifeCycleStopped(LifeCycle event) {
        LOG.debug("lifeCycleStopped()");
    }
```

I know this does not address your questions directly, but maybe you could provide us more information.

Comment: I was about to ask what the units were on setStopTimeout() but from above, it is millis.  Server.setStopTimeout() and all base class methods that are overridden should be better documented.